# InvalidOperationException not being caught

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a piece of code where I do this:

```
try{

      ... my code here ...

 }catch(Exception e){

   ... handle all exceptions here
 }
```

Inside my code an InvalidOperationException is being thrown. However, the catch is not trapping and handling it. How can I trap it? I thought "Exception" would catch everything inside the try?? I did a quick google search and apparently this is a common problem in Silverlight.

Comment: There's clearly not enough context here. What line inside of the `try` is throwing the exception? And are you sure it's not throwing inside the `catch`?

Comment: You're right about `Exception` matching all types of exceptions, however if the exception is thrown in a different thread, you won't catch it in this one. Also if it's caught and not rethrown inside the `try {}` part, this `catch` won't catch it.

Comment: Are you sure the exception is thrown within the try-block? If the exception is thrown within the catch-block it is not handled and will bubble up.

Comment: #C.Evenhuis I think you are right. This application is multi-threaded. I will check that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with this was that the exception was being thrown in a different thread. I tracked all the threads and set other try/catch in other places and sure enough I got it.